# D3.js - Text not appearing in circles

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to add text to circle i have created in d3.Js, but the text doesnt seem to be working. What am i doing wrong. The code is at http://pastebin.com/126mnFQa

Comment: You cannot append `text` elements to `circle` elements. They need to be appended either to the top-level SVG or a `g` element.

Comment: You cannot append a `text` element to a `circle` element, since the latter is not a grouping element. The common solution is to use a `g` (group) element to associate the two.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
var g = svg.append("g");
g.append("circle")
                      .attr("id","circle")
                      .attr("cx", 12 )
                      .attr("cy", 20)
                      .attr("fill",'red')
                      .attr("r", 20);
g.append("text").attr("dx",12).text(function(d){return radiusScale(5)})
```